# How to use a saved Octomap for Path Planning with Kinect

Tags: slam, navigation, kinect, octomap, vslam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am able to create very nice octomaps using kinect and rgbdslam detailed at the link below, but I do not understand how to use the saved map for path planning and the existing octomap and rgbdslam wiki's on ROS site do not have tutorials for how to do this yet. Can anyone direct me to a good tutorial for path planning with Kinect/RGBDSLAM using a saved Octomap?

Link to method for creating/saving octomap with kinect and rgbdslam: http://answers.ros.org/question/679/how-to-use-rgbd-6d-slam-for-path-planning-and

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10158/how-to-use-a-saved-octomap-for-path-planning-with-kinect/) by [Scott](https://answers.ros.org/users/100/scott/) on ROS Answers with karma: 693 on 2011-06-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Take a look at the [3d_navigation stack](http://www.ros.org/wiki/3d_navigation), that looks one of the few things that includes a planner and uses Octomap. Note that it's got "unreleased" and "experimental" notes on the wiki pages, so whether it will work or not at any given time, not sure.

In order to find other packages that might be useful, I suggest you take a look at the "Used by" link for the Octomap stack and it's individual packages (it's how I found 3d_navigation).

---

Originally posted by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) with karma: 8406 on 2011-06-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2